# How can I make popup like Win 10 notification popup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am current working on C# WPF project. I want to make dialog form like win10 right side notification manager for performing user CRUID operation, App setting etc

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make a custom control like the Windows notification center in WPF? or do you want to push a notification to the Windows notification center?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a custom control like the Windows notification center in WPF?